# Getting an attribute error in python code

Tags: python, pandas, attributes

How to set date column as an index? I'm getting an error

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's already an index. That would also explain the `AttributeError`. I'm only guessing but this may have happened if you moved your cells around executed cells out of order in Jupyter.

Comment: Could you provide the code how you are reading the data? If you have read the file having parameter ```set_index('Date')``` in ```pd.read_excel```, you will get ```AttributeError``` when trying to call ```df['Date']```.

Comment: df = web.DataReader('^BSESN', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2015-07-16', end = '2020-07-16')

Answer (score 0):

The Date column is already the index column, isn't it?
You can reset the index column and set it again like this if you want to try.
You will get the same result.

However, if you want to modify your Date column, you can do it by resetting the index column, modifying it, and then setting it back to the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

df = web.DataReader('^BSESN', data_source='yahoo', start='2015-07-16', end='2020-07-16')
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

# If you want to modify your index column, you can do it here.
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')

df.index = df['Date']
df.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already have `Date` as index.

To set any column as index, you can also try:

```py
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

This will set your `Date` column as index as well save your current index into DataFrame and will also make sure that there is no replica of `Date` present in the DataFrame.